# how to extract previous tag text

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am using `.prev('label')` to get the previous text from the label, but how how can i get the data or text 2 steps back from the label.

like how can i grab data from these following codes.

**HTML:**

```
<tr>
  <td width="25%">Name</td>
  <td width="75%"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="requiredField" /></td>
</tr>
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#sponsorshipForm').submit(function() {
        $('form#sponsorshipForm .error').remove();
        var hasError = false;
        $('.requiredField').each(function() {
            if(jQuery.trim($(this).val()) == '') {
                var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">You forgot to enter your '+labelText+'.</span>');
                hasError = true;
            } else if($(this).hasClass('email')) {
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
                if(!emailReg.test(jQuery.trim($(this).val()))) {
                    var labelText = $(this).prev('label').text();
                    $(this).parent().append('<span class="error">You entered an invalid '+labelText+'.</span>');
                    hasError = true;
                }
            }
        });
        if(!hasError) {
            $('form#sponsorshipForm li.buttons button').fadeOut('normal', function() {
                $(this).parent().append('<img src="/wp-content/themes/td-v3/images/template/loading.gif" alt="Loading&hellip;" height="31" width="31" />');
            });
            var formInput = $(this).serialize();
            $.post($(this).attr('action'),formInput, function(data){
                $('form#contactForm').slideUp("fast", function() {                 
                    $(this).before('<p class="thanks"><strong>Thanks!</strong> Your email was successfully sent. I check my email all the time, so I should be in touch soon.</p>');
                });
            });
        }

        return false;

    });
});
</script>
```

how can i extract "**Name**" because i am not using label here.

thank you

Comment: Please also show the JavaScript you're currently using.

Answer (score -1):

stop trying to do weird .prev( ) and getting text like that. just add the text as a custom attribute like `<input type="" custom-text="Name" />` or.... add the full object data in a javascript dictionary and reference it by the id or name of the input to get additional details like so...

```
var a = {};

a["name"] = { name: "Name" }

function getData( which )
{
    return a[which];
}
```

...something like that....but please don't walk up and down the html.